how to get the lazy loaded component with vue-router and getRoutes
I'm using vue 3.4.27 and vue-router 4.3.2 and I'm lazy loading some routes like this:
{
  path: '/path/to/pageone',
  component: () => import('../components/MyStuff/PageOne.vue')
},
{
  path: '/path/to/pagetwo',
  component: () => import('../components/MyStuff/PageTwo.vue')
},

I've got over a dozen of these; the site doesn't lend itself to dynamic routing for this part. My goal is to be able to get the current path, which I can do, then look up to see what other components are in the same folder and then pre-fetch them so they are available immediately instead of waiting to be downloaded when a router-link is clicked..  So if my current path is /path/to/pagefour I would get a list with something like:
'../components/MyStuff/PageOne.vue',
'../components/MyStuff/PageTwo.vue',
'../components/MyStuff/PageThree.vue',
'../components/MyStuff/PageFour.vue',

etc., because they are all associated with the /path/to/ route.
I've created a composable:
import { type Router } from 'vue-router';

export function usePrefetch(path: string = '', myRouter: Router): void {
  if (path === '') {
    return;
  }
  console.log(myRouter);
  console.log(myRouter.getRoutes());
}

All of my lazy loaded routes load as expected, the js files are downloaded when I click the router link. My composable is working because I can see myRouter and when I look at myRouter.getRoutes() I can see the array of routes with all of the paths.  But if I look at one of the routes, what I don't see is anything with the component: () => import('../components/MyStuff/PageOne.vue') information.  For non-lazy loaded routes I see the component listed.
Any ideas on how to get that data?  Would it be better to just import the router that is created with the createRouter function?
thanks!

Importing the router from my router file appears to be exactly the same as myRouter which is created from the useRouter() function.  I'd hoped I could get the raw routes file.  Shoot.

If you need route definitions then just export and import them. getRoutes are normalized routes. I'm not sure the original routes object is available through the router, I suspect it's not

Ok, I think I have a couple of more 'approved' ways of getting what I'm after
Use the Router object.

There are a few ways to get the Router object:


In the composable, import  router from '@/router'; Probably the best way of these three.
In the calling vue component, pass in $router (if using the options api, it is this.$router)
In the calling vue component, import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'; and then pass useRouter() to the composable


call getRoutes() on the Router object:  const allRoutes = router.getRoutes;
Get the current path: const currPath = router.currentRoute.value.path;
Iterate through all of the routes and look at the default component for each one, converting it to a string, and extracting the information that way. router.getRoutes().forEach( (route) => { console.log(route.components.default.toString()); } );
.default is a function, so that's why I converted it to a string, then I could parse it and find out where the component is loading from.

Use the meta field in the router
Since I'm already defining the route and which component to lazy load, it's easy to add a meta field that will give me the relative path to the file.
{
  path: '/path/to/pagetwo',
  component: () => import('../components/MyStuff/PageTwo.vue')
  meta: {
    file: '../path/to/file'
  }
}

Then I can iterate through the router object and access the path and meta data:
router.getRoutes().forEach( (route) => { 
  console.log(route.components.meta.file); 
  console.log(route.path);
} );

And go from there.
As much as I dislike casting the function to a string, it is probably the way to go because that will always tell me the path to the component on the server. Otherwise, if I changed where the site is deployed then I'd have to change the file location in meta or change the composable to parse the location differently.  Maybe there's some way to get the best of both worlds.  I'll have to think about it.
